# I want to know how wso2 api manager integrates solr

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I want to know how wso2 api manager integrates solr; why the search logic relies on solr instead of the database, and sometimes the records obtained by getallApis are not consistent with the number of records in the database table AM_API.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-documentation/search-documentation/add-new-search-keyword/) states WSO2 API Manager has **Apache Solr** based indexing for API documentation content. It provides both the API Publisher and Developer Portal a full-text search facility to search through the API documentation, and find the documents and related APIs.

I would recommend you to check out an excellent technical [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053050/why-is-solr-so-much-faster-than-postgres/10054078) of [@jpountz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675589/jpountz). Event though, the comparison made between **postgresql vs lucene** (underlying library is used by solr), it will give you some insight on why it's been chosen search engine (Lucene in the case wso2) over databases.

Comment: I want to know how wso2 integrates solr, is there a url of solr's management interface