# mysql + solr, or solr on its own

Tags: mysql, solr

Ive got the option to build an application storing the data in mysql and then using solr to speed up the queries for data.

However, im wondering whether it would be a good idea to skip mysql altogether and just use solr as the database? Is there any good reason why I should use mysql as the storage and solr as the fast index for the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Solr search index as a database - is this "wrong"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258593/using-solr-search-index-as-a-database-is-this-wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These DBs server different purposes, it very much depend on your application (and type of data you store) on whether you should use only Solr or also MySQL. MySQL is good to store data with a lot of relations and tables (tables related with each other). Solr is good to textual search (and as you say: fast index), and in case you do not have a lot of "related data" you can indeed store that data in the same documents. There are people that indeed are using only Solr to store their DBs... but I still think RDBMs can be nice for some types of data. For example: if you want to allow quick search on users of a system and also store their full profile, and several information details... It is good idea to use Solr for quick search of users (possibly retrieving their unique ID), but then MySQL (or also possibly some NoSQL DB... but this probably is another discussion) can be better candidate to store all the user related data (that does not need textual search).

Comment: This answered my question well. I have one big table (which can be used for solr) and then lots of small tables that are linked to it (facets) that use keys to retrieve the data. Cheers